# Test suite failed to run TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I try execute tests in React JS. I create dir **test**, my component has name 'component.test.js'. I install jest and other servies. My first bug is 'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module', I think I fix it. But now I have problem with cannot read property 'html'.

My code:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
import React from "react";
import LandingPage from "../components/LandingPage";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { MemoryRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
describe("LandingPage component", () => {
  it("Should render LandingPage component", () => {
    render(
      <Router>
        <LandingPage />
      </Router>
    );

    screen.debug();
    const signInInformation = screen.getByText("TEST");
    expect(signInInformation).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

I installed jest and I tried to exchange test-environment but it still doesn't work. I also try delete all node-modules and install again.

My dependencies:

```
"@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.18.6",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
"@types/react": "^18.0.21",
"babel-jest": "^29.3.1",
"babel-plugin-css-modules-transform": "^1.6.2",
"jest": "^29.3.1",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "^27.5.1",
```